# Need to split the data in the cell into different columns and help in copying data from website to excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

So i am copying the traffic data from [this](https://www.cp24.com/mobile/commuter-centre/traffic) website.

I have used the following code so far:

```
Sub main()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim i
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Navigate "https://www.cp24.com/mobile/commuter-centre/traffic"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = ReadyState_Complete

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.Document

Dim AllRoute As String

 Set holdingsClass = 
 Doc.getElementsByClassName("trafficWidget")
 ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = holdingsClass(0).textContent
IE.Quit
End Sub
```

There are two problems i am facing

1) It's copying all the data in traffic widget class into one cell so its deleting data when the cell runs out of space

2) I want a way to split the data so right now everything shows up in one cell

It should look like this

```
col.A          col.B            col.C         col.D
HighwayName    Current          Ideal         Delay
```

Any guidance would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go using [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to target the information required.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Getinfo()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument '< XMLHTTP60 is for Excel 2016 so change according to your versione.g. XMLHTTP for 2013

    Const URL As String = "https://www.cp24.com/mobile/commuter-centre/traffic"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim routeNodeList As Object, currentNodeList As Object, idealNodeList As Object, delayNodeList As Object

    With html
        Set routeNodeList = .querySelectorAll(".location")
        Set currentNodeList = .querySelectorAll(".current")
        Set idealNodeList = .querySelectorAll(".ideal")
        Set delayNodeList = .querySelectorAll(".delaymin")
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To routeNodeList.Length - 1
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(i + 2, 1) = routeNodeList.item(i).innerText
            .Cells(i + 2, 2) = currentNodeList.item(i).innerText
            .Cells(i + 2, 3) = idealNodeList.item(i).innerText
            .Cells(i + 2, 4) = delayNodeList.item(i).innerText
        End With
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

References required (VBE > Tools > References):

```
HTML Object library and MS XML < your version
```

---

Example output:

[image: Output]

---

Late bound version:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Getinfo()
    Dim http As Object, html As Object, i As Long
    Const URL As String = "https://www.cp24.com/mobile/commuter-centre/traffic"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Set html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Dim counter As Long: counter = 1
    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 0 To html.all.Length - 1
            Select Case html.all(i).className
            Case "location"
                counter = counter + 1
                .Cells(counter, 1).Value = html.all(i).innerText
            Case "current"
                .Cells(counter, 2).Value = html.all(i).innerText
            Case "ideal"
                .Cells(counter, 3).Value = html.all(i).innerText
            Case "delaymin"
                .Cells(counter, 4).Value = html.all(i).innerText
            End Select
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks perfect. Just having a slight problem with                                                      Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument    I have excel 2013 so not sure what XMLHTTP to use? is there a way i can check? Because its giving me a error right now

Comment: Try without the 60 first and let me know

Comment: I got it. Thank YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Curious, is there a way if i run the macro, it's going to paste after the last filled column so i can create a data repository?

Comment: Works Perfect. Thank you much